# Subtracting numpy arrays produces unexpected results

Tags: python, numpy

The following produces expected results:

```
import numpy as np

v1 = np.array([255, 0, 0])
v2 = np.array([250, 0, 0])

print(v1 - v2)
print(v2 - v1)
```

Results:

```
[255   0   0]
[250   0   0]
[5 0 0]
[-5  0  0]
```

However, the following, which should produce (IMHO) produce the same results, does not:

```
import numpy as np

image_array = np.zeros([2, 3, 3], dtype=np.uint8)
image_array[0,0] = np.array([255, 0, 0])
colors = np.zeros([3, 3], dtype=np.uint8)

colors[0] = np.array([250, 0, 0])
print(image_array[0,0])
print(colors[0])
print(image_array[0,0] - colors[0])
print(colors[0] - image_array[0,0])
```

Results:

```
[255   0   0]
[250   0   0]
[5 0 0]
[251   0   0]
```

Why is the last line not also?:

```
[-5  0  0]
```

Comment: `np.unit8` can’t be negative so when you subtract there’s an overflow error: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.unit8` can’t be negative so when you subtract there’s an overflow error: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that in the second case you dtype is  np.uint8 and it is unsigned datatype.
For `uint8` the values are `values=[0,1,...,251,252,253,254,255]`.  For -5, it starts from the smallest value, i.e. 0, and goes 5 places back in the values and reaches to 251.

Answer (score 0):

### dtype differs

The first variable `v1`'s dtype is `int64`:

```bash
v1 = np.array([255, 0, 0])
>>> v1.dtype
dtype('int64')
```

If we create np.ndarray without specifying dtype, and each element is float64 type, then it smartly assign it with `float64` type:

```bash
>>> v3 = np.array([255.0, 0.0, 0.0])
>>> v3.dtype
dtype('float64')
```

I think the keypoint for this question, is not "uint8 is in range [0, 255]". **It is `dtype` is very important for numpy's ndarray**. Unfortanately, I didn't find a good tool which checks computation result range overflows, such as the mentioned result in this question.

### example bug caused by uint8 subtract underflow

An example bug caused by the underflow of two uint8 subtraction, is when compute a gradient image.

```py
    img = cv2.imread("cat.jpeg")
    imgf = img.astype(np.float32)
    grad = np.empty_like(img)
    width, height, channel = img.shape
    for i in range(1, height - 1):
        for j in range(1, width - 1):
            #grad[j, i, :] = np.clip(img[j + 1, i, :] - img[j - 1, i, :], 0, 255) # generates bad result
            grad[j, i, :] = np.clip(imgf[j + 1, i, :] - imgf[j - 1, i, :], 0, 255) # generates expected result
```

Result image of subtraction with two uint8 (the bad one):
[image]

Result image of subtraction with two float (the expected result):
[image]

### Rust example

Rust language can found this underflow during compile-time. Example code:

```rust
fn main() {
    let a: u8 = 250;
    let b: u8 = 255;
    let c: u8 = a - b;
    //let c: u8 = a.wrapping_sub(b); // wrapping_sub for potential underflow
    println!("c = {}", c);
}
```

Compile the code, we can get a panic:

```bash
zz@localhost  rustc test.rs
error: this arithmetic operation will overflow
 --> test.rs:4:17
  |
4 |     let c: u8 = a - b;
  |                 ^^^^^ attempt to compute `250_u8 - u8::MAX`, which would overflow
  |
  = note: `#[deny(arithmetic_overflow)]` on by default

error: aborting due to previous error
```